# request addValue: forHTTPHeaderField gets the token but does not sends it to server in RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit, afnetworking

in my app, I have to get a token from my API, do a base 64 encoding with it, and then I have to attach it to all of my api requests.

**My Current situation**

Using AFNetworking, I set my custom header "Authorization" and send my token with my own base 64 encoding as username:password together,(that is why I am setting it like this is that of using the setAuthenticationwithusername: andPasswordmethod in RestKit). This is how I am making the call.

```
NSString *TokenAsaHeaderValue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@",EncodedToken];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.11.5.205:xxxx/"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/Games/Current/10" parameters:nil];
    [request addValue:TokenAsaHeaderValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation*operation,id responseObject)

    {
        self.JSONRESULTS = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"print this %@",_JSONRESULTS);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation*operation,NSError*error){NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);}];
        [operation start];
```

**my problem**

I am not sure how to map this. So I want to use RestKit for this call. But when i use nsurlrequest I can only use setValue, which does not adds the header. and when I try to send it as nsmutableurlrequest and add value this is the response I get:

**My trial**

Using RestKit, I mapped this json in app delegate and then using ObjectManager:

```
  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setValue:TokenAsaHeaderValue forKey:@"Authorization"];
```

and this is what I get as a response:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Authorization.'
```

(Also, the same mapping was working fine and I was able to get the objects before we implemented the Token request.)

**what would also help**
Example of how I can map this without RestKit with only AFNetworking.

I appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`setValue:forKey:` is the standard KVC method and has nothing to do with setting headers (directly anyway).

RestKit uses AFNetworking under the hood so your configuration that works can be reused by creating your object manager with the client ([`initWithHTTPClient:`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/initWithHTTPClient%3a)) you have or getting the client and configuring it ([`HTTPClient`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/HTTPClient)).